# SQL "Does a record exists"

Tags: sql

If you want to execute code, only when a certain row exists, what would be the correct way to check the exists? Previously, I have used varying methods, with little regards to the overall performance ... and wondered if there is a significant difference between the alternative approaches?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE...)

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYTABLE WHERE...) > 0
```

Is there a better way than the above?

Perhaps someone could offer the recommended approach and why that approach is better than the other ways?

Comment: Why would you want to count rows if you only want to know if one exists? So even if the execution plan would be the same the first approach is more readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dbms is smart enough to know that he doesn't need to retrieve anything from an EXISTS clause.

A maybe old but usual way to be explicit for user (but doesn't change anything for execution plan) is to use

```
if exists (select null from) --or select 1 from
```

but

```
if exists (select * from)
```

does the same.

An `EXISTS` clause tells better what you wanna achieve than your second version.

Comment: But does this answer compare the two approaches using `EXISTS` and `COUNT`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter now a little bit ;) But yes, I missed something first.

Answer (score 2):

The `exists` method is better in terms of performance.  It can stop processing the underlying table/query when it encounters the first record that matches.

The `count(*)` method has to actually produce the number of records, so it requires completing the underlying table scan/query.  And then, it also has to do an aggregation.

Yes, there can be a significant performance difference between them.  Say you have a table that has 100 million rows and you do:

```
if exists (select 1 from table t)
```

This will return almost instantaneously.

```
if (select count(*) from table t)
```

Has to do a full table scan, so go out and get a cup of coffee.

Use `exists`.